# How to configure the state of a Pmw RadioSelect checkbutton?

Tags: python, user-interface, configuration, tkinter

I have a Tk/Pmw interface that has a series of `Pmw.RadioSelect` widgets, only some of which should have active checkbuttons.  According to the [Pmw docs](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/howtouse.html), components (such as the `Tkinter.Checkbutton` in the RadioSelect widget) can be configured using underscores to indicate inheritance.  In the example on that page, the background of the `Tkinter.Entry` widget in the `Entryfield` component of the `Pmw.Counter` megawidget called `counter` can be configured in the following manner.

```
counter.configure(entryfield_entry_background = 'yellow')
```

For [RadioSelect](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/RadioSelect.html) widgets, however, the names of the button components and their inheritance aren't explicitly given in the documentation, since the buttons can be different types (`button`, `radiobutton`, and `checkbutton`).

**How can one configure the `Checkbutton` component of the `RadioSelect` widget?**  Basically I just need the right string to pass as an argument to configure.  I've done some searching and trial-and-error, and haven't found the right argument name yet.

For reference, here's a simplified version of what I have so far.  It's a list of separate items that can each be checked or unchecked, but some of the checkboxes should be inactive.

```py
for i, f in enumerate(foo):

    # Create the RadioSelect widget
    chk = Pmw.RadioSelect(parent,
            buttontype='checkbutton',
            command=self.checkbutton_callback)

    # Add a numbered checkbutton
    chk.add(str(i))

    # Place it on the grid
    chk.grid(row=i, column=0)

    # Without the following code, it works fine, but all the buttons are enabled
    # With it, the program chokes on the `configure()` call
    if not f.active:
        print "This gets printed."
        chk.configure(checkbutton_state='disabled')
        print "But this doesn't."
```

Clearly `checkbutton_state` in the second-to-last line is the wrong argument name.  What should I use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`add()`](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/RadioSelect.html) method returns the component widget. This mean you can modify this line:

```
chk.add(str(i))
```

To:

```
my_checkbutton = chk.add(str(i))
```

Put this in mind. Now to use a `my_checkbutton`, you must create a Tkinter variable `my_var = IntVar()` because if you want to  inspect the state of `my_checkbutton` , query `my_var`.

If this is not clear to you, I can provide you my sample program. which screenshot is above:

[image]